# Can I make orthophosphoric acid from sodium dihydrogen phosphate and an acid which I can use to make ethyl iodide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, alcohols, halogenation, amides

For my project I needed to di-substitute benzamide with ethyl group at N position to create DEB as a mosquito repellent. The first part of creating benzamide I was able to do, but the second part of substituting is a bit hard for me. I wanted to substitute using ethyl iodide as it was not a gas while the bromide and chloride was a gas.

Our lab apparently did not have the orthophosphoric acid to create hydroiodic acid in situ, so I resorted to using chloroethane, but I wasn't able to do it due to complications in my bubbling setup. Then I thought I could prepare orthophosphoric acid from sodium dihydrogen phosphate as it is available in our lab. Can someone help me on doing it,
or is there any other method to do it without the above methods?

The available materials are ethanol, $\ce{KI}$, $\ce{NaH2PO4}$, $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{HNO3}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$, and there is no hydroiodic acid.

Comment: Isn't it easier to react benzoyl chloride with diethylamine?

Comment: I wanted to do it but I wasn't sure how to exactly di-ethylate ammonia and went ahead with making the amide.

Comment: Diethylamine is widely commercially available

Comment: Ethyl bromide is liquid, unless you need high temperature. Even cold chloride is.

Comment: Thanks @Mithoron but I was able to do it by the method given by Maurice. i didn't know it was EtBr was a liquid. but i wasn't able to EtCl as the benzamide wouldn't dissolve so i had to heat it and due to this i wan't able to use it in cold condition.

Comment: @Waylander it wasn't available in my lab as it was a pretty basic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phosphoric acid can be produced from sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$, as it reacts with sodium dihydrogen phosphate $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ to produce phosphoric acid $\ce{H3PO4}$ according to :  $$\ce{NaH2PO4 + H2SO4 -> NaHSO4 + H3PO4}$$ Phosphoric acid can be used to produce $\ce{HI}$ even if it is mixed with $\ce{NaHSO4}$.

Comment: Thank you @Maurice. I was able to do it using the above method. The output came out with good yield and it even resulted in good looking crystals of DEB.